# How to stop active threads in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor throught jmx

Tags: java, spring, task

in my app I am using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. This executor contains method which return activeThread `getActiveCount` . Is there option how to stop this active threads ? I dont want to shutdown this executor I just want to stop some infinity process like

```
while(true){
}
```

PS: I have access just to this executor because  I want to stop this thread through jmx

In my app I am add new threads like this:

```
                taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doSomething()
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a quick check as to how you are adding the tasks.

So long as you are using submit to add the tasks you can use the Future task which is returned (from this call) to cancel specific tasks. However if you use execute you are reliquishing control over the task.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        doSomething();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //Very important.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Shutting down thread");
}
```

This is a good article [javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue056.html](http://javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue056.html%20ception%20javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue056.html)